# SDL2 doesn't render multiple viewports

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

I'm working through Lazy Foo's SDL2 tutorials and stuck trying to render multiple [viewports](http://lazyfoo.net/faq.php). The idea is to load a PNG as a texture, create `SDL_Rect` structs for 3 different viewports (top left, top right, bottom), then copy the texture onto each viewport, and finally render all 3 viewports. My code is only rendering the first viewport.

I've tried changing the order - in every case, whichever viewport is defined first is the only one that renders.

I also tried changing the viewport dimensions, in case overlap was the issue - same problem.

The only [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59913756/c-sdl2-how-to-render-rects-into-multiple-viewports) I found about multiple viewports didn't point me in the right direction. But it did start me thinking - my code is written in C, the tutorial in C++. Although I think I'm translating everything correctly (the other lessons work fine), maybe I'm missing something obvious here?

I'm compiling with `CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99` - no warnings or errors.

Edit: I tried rendering filled rectangles instead of a loaded PNG, but the issue is the same - only the first one renders.

Here's my code:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 640
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 480

int init_renderer();
int load_media();
SDL_Texture *load_texture(char *);
void close_renderer();

SDL_Window *g_window = NULL;
SDL_Renderer *g_renderer = NULL;
SDL_Texture *g_texture = NULL;

int main()
{
  if (init_renderer() != 1) {
    return -1;
  }

  if (!SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "1")) {
    printf("Warning: Linear texture filtering not enabled!\n");
  }

  if (load_media() != 1) {
    return -1;
  }

  int quit = 0;
  SDL_Event e;
  while (quit != 1) {
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) {
      if (e.type == SDL_QUIT || e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_q) {
        quit = 1;
      }
    }

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(g_renderer, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff);
    SDL_RenderClear(g_renderer);

    SDL_Rect top_left_vp;
    top_left_vp.x = 0;
    top_left_vp.y = 0;
    top_left_vp.w = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
    top_left_vp.h = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;
    SDL_RenderSetViewport(g_renderer, &top_left_vp);
    SDL_RenderCopy(g_renderer, g_texture, NULL, NULL);

    SDL_Rect top_right_vp;
    top_right_vp.x = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
    top_right_vp.y = 0;
    top_right_vp.w = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
    top_right_vp.h = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;
    SDL_RenderSetViewport(g_renderer, &top_right_vp);
    SDL_RenderCopy(g_renderer, g_texture, NULL, NULL);

    SDL_Rect bottom_vp;
    bottom_vp.x = 0;
    bottom_vp.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;
    bottom_vp.w = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    bottom_vp.h = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;
    SDL_RenderSetViewport(g_renderer, &bottom_vp);
    SDL_RenderCopy(g_renderer, g_texture, NULL, NULL);

    SDL_RenderPresent(g_renderer);
  }

  close_renderer();

  return 0;
}

int init_renderer()
{
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
    printf("Failed to initialize SDL. Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return 0;
  }

  g_window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tuts",
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                              SCREEN_WIDTH,
                              SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                              SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

  if (g_window == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to create window. Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return 0;
  }

  g_renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(g_window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
  if (g_renderer == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to create renderer. Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    return 0;
  }

  SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(g_renderer, 0x29, 0xAB, 0x87, 0xFF);

  int img_flags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
  if (!(IMG_Init(img_flags) & img_flags)) {
    printf("Failed to initialize SDL Image. SDL_Image Error: %s\n", IMG_GetError());
    return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}

int load_media()
{
  g_texture = load_texture("assets/texture.png");
  if (g_texture == NULL) {
    return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}

SDL_Texture *load_texture(char *path)
{
  SDL_Texture *new_texture = NULL;
  SDL_Surface *loaded_surface = IMG_Load(path);
  if (loaded_surface == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to load image. SDL_Image Error: %s\n", IMG_GetError());
  } else {
    new_texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(g_renderer, loaded_surface);
    if (new_texture == NULL) {
      printf("Failed to create texture from %s. Error: %s\n", path, SDL_GetError());
    }

    SDL_FreeSurface(loaded_surface);
  }

  return new_texture;
}

void close_renderer()
{
  SDL_DestroyTexture(g_texture);
  g_texture = NULL;

  SDL_DestroyRenderer(g_renderer);
  SDL_DestroyWindow(g_window);
  g_renderer = NULL;
  g_window = NULL;

  IMG_Quit();
  SDL_Quit();
}
```

Comment: Are all of those SDL_* functions synchronous?  You're exiting main immediately after rendering the last window.  Could it be the rendering is happening on a back-ground thread and your process exits before all the queued work is completed?

Comment: @jwdonahue great question. I think because the rendering is wrapped in a `while` loop, that will only break if the user presses `Q` or exits the program it should allow all the rendering to complete.

Comment: @red.connors That's correct. You've rendered everything to the screen and presented the screen, so as long as the while loop doesn't close, the thread handling rendering will complete before the main thread closes.

Comment: Can't reproduce. What OS/renderer/SDL version? High DPI?

Comment: @keltar MacOS 10.15.2, SDL 2.0.10, SDL_Image 2.0.5. Not sure about the renderer, but I can get other programs in the tutorial to run fine. It's strictly the multiple viewports that cause an issue. I doubt it's the case, but I'm converting the global variables to pointers - maybe there's a memory issue somewhere?

Comment: @red.connors any change with `SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_DRIVER, "opengl")` between SDL_Init and window creation?

Comment: @keltar yeah that does make a change - it renders the 3 viewports in the bottom left corner of the screen. from my understanding of the tutorials, this shouldn't be rendered with OpenGL. Am I missing something?

Comment: @keltar you put me on the right track! I looked at the SDL docs for `SDL_Hint` and tried the `software` flag (instead of `opengl`) and it worked. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Do you want to write this up in an answer and I'll select it?

Comment: @keltar I was having a similar issue and using `SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE` solved it. But why? This seems like a bug to me. The only difference between the software driver and the OpenGL driver should be performance right?

Comment: It actually turned out to be a problem with the Metal driver which is even more concerning. Switching over to OpenGL solved the issue for me. I kind of expect bugs to appear when using OpenGL on MacOS but not Metal! So, is this a bug or not?

Comment: @Kerndog73 yes looks like a bug. Why do you think it is in metal driver itself, can you provide any info leading to that conclusion? Also almost everything have bugs, that shouldn't be truly unexpected.

Comment: @keltar Well I did `SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_DRIVER, "metal")` and it was broken. Then I did `SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_DRIVER, "opengl")` and it was working.

Comment: @red.connors sorry I don't think this is actually an answer, more of a temporary workaround (we don't know when apple kills its GL). If possible, consider making minimal reproducible example (i.e. without texture and SDL_image but just fillrect) and filing a bug to SDL bugzilla. I can't verify it as I don't have a mac nearby.

Comment: @Kerndog73 then we don't know if there is a problem in SDL's metal renderer or apple's metal driver itself. Extra debugging required.

Comment: I think I might file a bug report. If I do, I'll leave a link

Comment: Turns out this has already been reported. https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4960

Comment: @keltar Makes sense. Since there's a bug report already open I'll just keep on eye on that link.

Answer (score 0):

To check for more errors, you should see what the calls to `SDL_RenderSetViewPort` are returning. According to [the docs](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderSetViewport), it returns an int, which is 0 on success or a negative int if there's an error. It's entirely possible that something deeper in SDL is having a fit.

Additional pro tips: you can define the `SDL_Rect` structs outside of your while loop to save a miniscule margin of processing power. And to spare yourself some typing, you can initialize a SDL_Rect using a list constructor instead of manually punching each property. E.G.:

```
SDL_Rect top_left_vp;
top_left_vp.x = 0;
top_left_vp.y = 0;
top_left_vp.w = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;
top_left_vp.h = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2;
```

is more simply

```
SDL_Rect top_left_vp = {
    0,
    0,
    SCREEN_WIDTH / 2,
    SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I'm not getting any errors when calling `SDL_RenderSetViewport` or any other non-void SDL functions. And thanks for the pro tips!

Comment: @red.connors In that case, the next thing I'd think to try is to set your viewport to NULL right before you call RenderPresent. I halfway doubt that's the issue, but it's also good practice to clean up things after tinkering with them.

Comment: I set the viewport to NULL with `SDL_RenderSetViewport(g_renderer, NULL);` but it didn't change anything. Good call on cleaning up, though